# BitBucket shows two commits from two different branches

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have the following problem. When I create a pull request in BitBucket and look at the commits, I see a list of commits from two different branches. One commit of the target Branch and one commit of another branch. The other branch I already pushed to BitBucket (but not created a pull request of this). How can I fix this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To fit in the SO standards of questions, it would be better if you included more information on the issue you have at hand, for example a view of how your commits are ordered. I think I guessed the issue you have, but I am not 100% sure, please add more details if this wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably in a situation where you based your development on another branch, which isn't merged in master yet.

One of the two following diagrams :

```
* ee3127 (master) some more commits on master
| * dd7162 (feature) the feature I want to merge into master
| | * cc8763 (otherbranch) some other undergoing development
| |/
| * bb7672 a commit, which is not part of master
|/
* aa8179 the state of master when one of the branch was created
```

If you want a branch, which forks off master, and contains only the commits found "only in `feature`", you can use rebase :

```
# the 'bb' commit represents the fork point between your branch and otherbranch
git rebase --onto master bb7672 feature
```